# ZABBIX : Should I need to add the ListenIP in all my host machines zabbix-agentd.conf file?

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

zabbix-agentd.conf file in HOST:

```
### Option: ListenIP
#       List of comma delimited IP addresses that the agent should listen on.
#       First IP address is sent to Zabbix server if connecting to it to retrieve list of active checks.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# ListenIP=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: `Mandatory: no`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config shows the default value, which is `0.0.0.0`. This means it listens on all interfaces. You only need to specify the option when you want the Zabbix agent to listen only on specific interfaces. Otherwise you just can leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

It can be handy, if you want to separate production traffic away from management traffic. Especially with production interfaces that need to deal with the header part of the data, like a proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is optional and I never heard of someone using it.
If you do not specify this option, the Zabbix agent will listen on all ip addresses of your computer.